# PDF file displayed as "text/html" in the browser

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, content-type

Context : Apache in front of a Weblogic application Server.

A user can download a PDF file through our J2EE application. 
With Weblogic alone, the PDF is displayed correctly in the plugin in all browsers.

But with Apache, the HTTP response header has `Content-type "text/html"` in it (as we can see in Firebug for example), which leads the web browser to display the file inline as text. 
What we send in the HTTP header from our Java code : 
`Content-Disposition` -> name of the PDF, and `Expires` -> 0

No Content-type is set (to simplify, let's say we do not know the type of the file in our application), and it is not possible for us to change that.

It seems that Apache overrides that and sets its own `Content-type`, why ? 
We tried to set `DefaultType none` in the `httpd.conf` but without effect.

Of course, this is the same for all file types, PDF is only an example.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem yesterday.  In my case, I found that when I (inadvertently) wasn't setting any Content-Type value on the HTTP Response from my WebLogic application, Apache would "helpfully" notice this, and set a Content-Type header with of `text/html` -- even though the content I was returning to the client was a binary PDF.

This resulted in the raw binary PDF content being displayed in the client browser as if it were plain text.

It may be possible to suppress this behavior in Apache.  However, in my case, the solution I landed on was to set a Content-Type on the HTTP response object *before* committing the response.

(In my application, an Oracle ATG Commerce app running on WebLogic, any calls to `DynamoHttpServletResponse.setContentType()` or `DynamoHttpServletResponse.setHeader()` after calling `flush()` on the response object's outputStream were being silently ignored.)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try to find the filetype and fill the Content-type. Any other way would be non-standard and can give you problems depending on browser.

The filetypes can be determined using

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
```

or

```
String fileName = "/path/to/file";
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();

// only by file name
String mimeType = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(fileName);

// or by actual File instance
File file = new File(fileName);
mimeType = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);
```

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to avoid that and understand why Apache is changing the content-type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the apache module [mime_magic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime_magic.html) helps?

If it doesn't, then you could save the file in some directory inside www_root and send a redirect to the browser which leads to this file. That way, only apache itself sends the file back, and using mime_magic it can set the correct content-type too.